# como creo dropDownList con Entity Framework en Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estoy *iniciando* un nuevo proyecto y estoy migrando de webForm a MVC y confieso que me saltan dudas a lo mejor básicas para algunos.

Bueno una de esas preguntas es la siguiente, necesito crear un dropDownList y los datos de este tanto el ID como el Nombre los tengo en una tabla en base de datos. La persistencia de los datos lo trabajo con Entity Framework.

¿Como hago para enviar los datos desde el modelo? ¿ me podrían ayudar con un ejemplo ?

Por ahora lo he realizado desde el controlador y tengo el siguiente código

De esta manera, desde el *controlador* puedo llenar el dropDownList

```
// controlador 
    public ActionResult Index()
            {

                using (var contextoBd = new SGDCONSULTA_Entidades())
                {
                    var usuarios = (from sd in contextoBd.t_SoportesDocumentales
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        sd.Id,
                                        sd.NombreSoporte
                                    }).ToList();

                    usuarios.Add(new { Id = 0, NombreSoporte = "-- Seleccione -- " });

                    var listaUsuarios = new SelectList(usuarios.OrderBy(o => o.Id), "Id", "NombreSoporte");

                    ViewData["usuarios"] = listaUsuarios;
                }
                return View();
            }
```

y desde la vista hago lo siguiente

```
@Html.DropDownList("usuarios", ViewData["usuarios"] as SelectList, new { @id = "dlUsuarios", @class = "form-control" })
```

Pero ahora si quisiera hacer esto pero desde el modelo como podría hacerlo? ademas, es aconsejable esto? hacerlo desde el modelo ?

De ante mano muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos jeissoni22, bienvenido al sitio, hace un tiempo hice un workshop sobre ASP.net MVC desde cero, espero te sea de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY + código fuente en Github https://github.com/fredyfx/UPAOnetStackOverflowES-ASPnetMVC

Hay varias maneras, te presento una de ellas mediante un ViewBag desde el controlador donde creas una lista:

```
List<Estudiante> lEstudiantes = new List<Estudiante>();
lEstudiantes = db.Estudiantes.ToList();
ViewBag.listaEstudiantes = lEstudiantes;
```

Y en tu vista:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Estudiante", new SelectList(ViewBag.listaEstudiantes, "ID", "Nombres"))
```

Otra manera manera es mediante un Modelo que le pasarás a la lista. En tu controlador:

```
var modelo = new cEstudianteViewModel();
modelo.listaEstudiantes = ObtenerListaEstudiantes();
```

y en tu vista:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Estudiante", new SelectList(Modelo.listaEstudiantes, "ID", "Nombres")) 
//"ID"-> Key, "Nombres" -> Value.
```